# Google Website Optimizer not tracking conversions

Tags: web, google-analytics, optimization

In a nutshell my split tests aren't tracking conversions at all.

My A/B pages are on http://www.mydomain.com, and my conversion page is the last stage of my shopping cart on https://secure.mydomain.com.

I thought the most concise way of explaining this would be to post my page source code:

http://pastebin.com/ru7dCDqD

To summarize, the pages are being displayed correctly in my test report, but no conversions are being tracked.

Comment: You seem to have everything configured correctly, I wish I could say I spotted an error for you. Have you tried reading through the Techie Guide? http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer/techieguide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be occurring because your shopcart page is on a separate subdomain.  Follow the GWO instructions for cross-domain tracking and see if this helps:

http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151978

It may be as simple as adding this line of code to your conversion and tracking scripts:

gwoTracker._setDomainName(".mydomain");

Having the "." in there is important as it allows for all of the subdomains underneath your primary to be tracked, as well.